# Creating A Shortcut/desktop Icon To Run dotnet console application

Tags: terminal, applescript, applications, automator, script

Total newb to macs here...

I've got a dotnet application that runs on my macbook. I can manually open a terminal and run `dotnet myapp.dll` and the application runs.

I've put that single command into a shell script and I can run that shell script in terminal. I had to run `sudo chmod 755 myscript.sh` to allow it to run.

I read a few other questions which mentioned using apple script and automator. I've tried both and I get an error
"dotnet command not found"

I'm stuck at the moment.

How can I make this work? Second, If I'm trying to distribute this application to a few computers, is there a better/simple/easy way to package this all up so it just works?

Per Comments:
echo $PATH yields
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`

Comment: The problem is probably your path - it is not the same in GUI and terminall - what does `echo $PATH` say (although a properly instyalled dotnet should not have that issue - for that what does ls /etc/paths/d show)

Comment: @mmmmmm added $PATH location to question.  `ls /etc/paths/d` yielded "Not a directory"

Comment: Sorry I made a typo ls /etc/paths.d but your $PATH shows that is correct.  dotnet should be in /usr/local/share/dotnet Do you have that directory and what is in it?

Comment: @mmmmmm `dotnet dotnet-cli-tools mono-commands`

Comment: Hmm.... OK in automator/applescript instead of just dotnet put in the whole path of the dotnet executable. Id the app a GUI one or just command line?

Comment: I just installed dotnet using Homebrew. Then in Terminal I ran which dotnet and it returned “/usr/local/bin/dotnet” so if I’m trying to create an AppleScript applet with the do shell script command, I would use the entire path like this… do shell script "/usr/local/bin/dotnet " & quoted form of "/path/to/application.dll"

Comment: @wch1zpink This works.. but something weird is going on. It's like there' are some restrictions on resource loading. While the dotnet command in terminal fully loads my application.